# DHT routing library for Java

Tags: java, routes, dht

I need some sort of routing library, similar to openkad, which does not provide any hashtable functionality but simply provides facilities to

- register new node in the network
- receive a message when object with key should be handled by us (saved in local database/filesystem/etc, removed)
- receive a message when object should be retrieved

so I rather need some sort of router implementation in Java.